# SSH-client on windows that supports ECDSA

Tags: ssh, encryption, putty

I'm looking for a ssh-client on windows that supports [ecdsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_DSA).

There is [a whish](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/ecdsa.html) for putty, but no support yet.

Winscp [is waiting](http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13118) for putty to implement it.

It seems to me that there is no client that supports ecdsa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tera Term does support ECDSA keys: http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/

Comment: TeraTerm looks very good. Even has support for solarized in the default ini file. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

OpenSSH version coming with Cygwin supports ECDSA keys since… since SSH itself supports them. If you have Cygwin installation up and running, you can make a simple link or batch script to `mintty /usr/bin/ssh …whatever options you might need…` and have very much PuTTY-like visuals with all the power of OpenSSH. If you don't have Cygwin setup, I suggest checking it.

Also, daily PuTTY snapshots currently contain ECDSA support. (0.64 beta release does not include it.)